# Get records created in last 24 hours

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to get documents that were created in the last 24 hours, and return the count. I'm currently adding the documents like this:

```py
def add_game(game_id):
    data = {
        "game_id":game_id,
        "started":datetime.date.now()
    }
    mongo.db['GameData'].insert_one(data)
```

I'm trying to retrieve the documents like this, but it's no returning anything even though there is documents in there:

```py
def get_game_count_last_24_hours():
    data = {
        "started": {
            "$lt":datetime.datetime.now(),
            "$ge":datetime.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        }
    }
    return mongo.db['GameData'].find(data).count()
```

Any reasons as to why? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have 2 minor syntax mistakes in your code

1. you're using `datetime.today()` instead of `datetime.datetime.today()`
2. you're trying to use `$ge` which is nothing, instead of `$gt`.

With these minor fixes your code works:

```
def get_game_count_last_24_hours():
    data = {
        "started": {
            "$lt": datetime.datetime.now(),
            "$gt": datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        }
    }
    return mongo.db['GameData'].find(data).count()
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I'll mark your answer as solved.